# Images will not center with CSS

Tags: html, css, image, class, centering

Just turned in a programming assignment for my class and was talking to the teacher when he told me I was not allowed to use  to center my images. He said I had to use id and class and then center in the stylesheet/CSS. This makes no sense to me, when I use the inline  it works perfectly but I have tried everything I know to center in the stylesheet and nothing works. I have attached 2 examples from my code:

This works perfectly on centering image but the professor says it is not allowed:

```
<h5>Back View</h5>
    <div style="text-align: center"/>
    <a href="BackViewT-Shirt.html" target="_blank">
      <img src="http://i1293.photobucket.com/albums/b581/AlaskanAdventureApparel/photo1_zpsff666fce.jpg" height="400" width="300" alt="Back View Alaskan Adventure T-Shirt"/>
    </a>
```

Then tried using an id and class and nothing has worked, trying to center both the heading and the image:

**HTML:**

```
<h5 class="center">Back View</h5>
    <a href="BackViewT-Shirt.html" target="_blank">
      <img src="http://i1293.photobucket.com/albums/b581/AlaskanAdventureApparel/photo1_zpsff666fce.jpg" height="400" width="300" alt="Back View Alaskan Adventure T-Shirt"/>
    </a>
```

**StyleSheet:**

```
.center {
text.align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your markup is wrong, you dropped the container div:

```
<h5>Back View</h5>
<div class="center">
 <a href="BackViewT-Shirt.html" target="_blank">
  <img src="http://i1293.photobucket.com/albums/b581/AlaskanAdventureApparel/photo1_zpsff666fce.jpg" height="400" width="300" alt="Back View Alaskan Adventure T-Shirt"/>
 </a>
</div>
```

Also, you CSS has a typo (ALWAYS VALIDATE!)

```
.center {
   text-align: center;
}
```

Here, the `div` aligns its inline contents.

As an aside, you could also do something like:

```
a{
  display:block;
  width:200px; /* This should be the width of the image */
  margin:0 auto; /* This cryptic statement will center block-level elements */
 }
```

Comment: Validation is more of a guideline than anything else.

Comment: @Nit Sorry very new to how the comment box works, but thank you for your input.

Comment: @AlaskanDownSouth Glad things worked out, feel free to accept this as the answer by clicking the check box if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

```
.center {
   text-align: center;
 }
```

you used text.align instead of text-align

Answer (score 0):

Your stylesheet also has a typo in it.

```
.center {
text.align: center;
}
```

Should be

```
.center {
text-align:center;
}
```